# Understanding relations in django models fields

Tags: python, django, django-models

I get all fields of some model `MyModel._meta.get_fields()` and then I process them and want to understand which of them added by myself and which by django. 
For example if I have class Moovie and class Comedy which have `moovie = models.ForeignKey(Moovie, on_delete=models.CASCADE)`, when i will get fields `Moovie._meta.get_fields()` field moovie will be in this list too, and if other models link to Moovie model, moovie field will be in list several times. I need skip them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, sorry, that is my answer

```
def field_name(field, ModelClass=None):
    if hasattr(field, 'field') and 'get_attname_column' in dir(field.field):
        return field.field.get_attname_column()[0]
    if 'get_attname_column' in dir(field):
        return field.get_attname_column()[0]

    field = field.field if hasattr(field, 'field') else ModelClass._meta.get_field(field.field_name)
    return field.get_attname_column()[0]

def checkClassHasField(modelClass, field):
    name = field_name(field)
    try:
        modelClass._meta.get_field(name)
        return True
    except Exception:
        return False
```

I can filter `MyModel._meta.get_fields()` list by this function.
However may be better way is exists...

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look into [Django Model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/models/#fields), your requirement will be fixed by this.